# How the custom component of category items show in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-commerce

A custom component is added for Sitecore Commerce **SellableItem**. When we update the commerce **Data Templates**, the custom component Templates are generated under `Catalog Generated/Components/ConnectSellableItem`.

[image]

Also those fields are showing up under site's catalog product items.

But for **Category** Custom components, the custom templates are not generating by default like the ConnectSellableItem as shown above.
Is there any configuration required, so that the data provider can generate those custom component Templates of Category?

Comment: Can u verify that the composer has been added to Category as linked entities? (business tools --> composer --> category composer check Linked Entities.

Comment: I haven't used Composer, I used component concept as mentioned in this [link](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/083614)

Comment: Well that was the case in Sitecore 9.0.2. With newer version of sitecore, you can use composer templates and link it to entites and just update templates in sitecore cms.

Comment: yes, you are right, but the reason why we are using Component approach is because the component field values are coming from external system and need to update frequently using minion, in component approach updating the component is very easy. 


I fixed the issue, it was code issue, i missed to pass component fields as ViewProperties in ConnectViewBlock.

When Component fields passed in ConnectView block, it started showing in the Content Tree